# embedded profiler

Tags: profiler, mips

I am supposed to profile/optimize an application. I am running on a mips machine so valgrind is not an option. Any tool suggestions, tactics?

EDIT: I guess I should have given more details. Gprof is not supported in my toolchain. I have tried oprofile; but results seemed incorrect, also I could not get a calltree. I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the GNU toolchain (gcc et al) then you can use `gprof`. It's crude, but it works.

If your OS is Linux then you might also check whether `oprofile` is supported on MIPS.

Answer (score 0):

The method I've relied on for three decades, for all such problems, on all kinds of machines and operating systems, [is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

**gprof** is nearly as old and reliable, but is [very limited in what it will do for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).

Comment: Code is huge and has a decent performance (ie: it does not get stuck in loops). But it needs further optimization to be more responsive. I am not sure if start/stop will help.

Comment: @l.thee.a: It will. You'll see.

Comment: @l.thee.a: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624667/whats-a-very-easy-c-profiler-vc/2624725#2624725

Answer (score 0):

The [SD Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers) is a family of code profilers based on langauge-accurate parsers used to temporarily instrument your code.  These profilers cover C, C++, Java, C#, PHP and COBOL.

The profilers have very low footprint and overhead, and are thus ideal for embedded systems.  You didn't say what langauge, so I'll guess you are interested in C or C++.

However, you need to be more specific about which (C/C++) dialect you are using.