# Adding more hardware v/s refactoring code under a time crunch

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, performance, xml-serialization

Background:
Enterprise application - very will written for its time in 2004.

Stack:
.NET, Heavy use of Remoting, ASMX style web services, SQL Server

Problem:
The application allows user to go through various wizards for lack of a better term, all of their actions are stored in what we call "wiz state", which is essentially XML that is persisted to a SQL server database very frequently because we allow users to pause/resume their application. Often in these wizards, the XML that comprises the wizard state grows very large, I'm talking 5-8 MB of data, and we noticed that when we had a sudden influx of simultaneous users, we started receiving occasional timeouts against the database, because a lot of what the wizard state is comprised of, is keeping track of collections of "things". Sometimes these custom collections grow very large.

Question:
We were in a meeting today and we're expecting a flurry of activity in October that will test the system like never before, and possibly result in huge wizard states that go back and forth from the web server to the database. The crux of the situation is that there is only one database and one web server.

For arguments sake, because of the complexity of the application, lets say adding any kind of clustering/mirroring to increase database throughput is out of the question. I spoke up in the meeting and said the quickest way to address this in the shortest time period would be to add more servers to the front end web application so the load could be distributed amongst web servers. The development lead said I was completely wrong and it would have no effect because we only have one database, so adding more web power would do nothing. He is having one of the other developers reduce the xml bloat that we persist frequently to the database. Probably in the long run, reducing the size of the xml that we pass back and forth is the right idea, but will adding additional web servers truly have no effect, I just think in terms of simultaneous users, it *should* help.

Any responses thoughts are appreciated, proof that more web servers would help would be pure win.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: We use binary serialization to store the XML in the database in an image field.

Comment: I would agree with your lead on adding web servers will not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard anything about locating the "bottlenecks". Isn't that the first thing to do? [Here's the method I use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624667/whats-a-very-easy-c-profiler-vc/2624725#2624725)
Otherwise you're just investing in guesses. That won't work.

I've been in meetings like that, where everybody gets excited throwing ideas around, and "management" wants to make "decisions", but it's the blind leading the blind. Knuckle down and *find out* what's going on. You can't do that in meetings.

Some time ago I looked at a performance problem with some similarity to yours. The biggest "bottleneck" was in writing and parsing XML, with attendant memory allocation, setup, and destruction. Then there were others as well. You might find the same thing, or something different.

P.S. I keep quoting "bottleneck" because all the performance problems I've found have been nothing at all like the necks of bottles. Rather they are like way over-bushy call trees that need radical pruning, such as making and reading mountains of XML for no good reason.

Answer (score 2):

If the rate at which the data is written by SQL is the bottleneck, feeding data to SQL more quickly should have no effect.

I am not sure exactly what the data structure is, but perhaps compressing the XML data on the web server(s) before writing may have a positive effect.

Comment: +1 for Compression. XML contains a lot of highly repetitive data (and just how long are your tags?)

Answer (score 2):

If the bottleneck is the database, then more web services will not help you a lot.

The problem may be that the problem is not only the size of the data, but the number of concurrent request to the same table. The number of writes will be the big problem. If your XML write is in a transaction with other queries you may try to break out the XML write from that transaction to reduce locking time of the XML table.

As stated by vdeych you may try compression to reduce the data size. (That would increase the load on the web servers.)

You may also try caching the data. Only read from the SQL server if the data is not already in the cache. Make sure you don't update the SQL server if your data has not changed.

Answer (score 2):

No one seems to have suggest this, what about replacing your XML serialization of your wizard with JsonSerialization.

Not only should this give you a minor boost in performance in the serialization itself since both the DataContractSerializer (faster) and Newtonsoft Json.NET (fastest) out perform the XML serializers in .NET. This should easily reduce the size of your object graph by upwards of 50% or more (depending on number of properties vs large strings in the XML).

This should dramatically lower the IO that is inflicted upon Sql server. This should also limit the amount of scope required to alter your application significantly (assuming it's well designed and works through common calls for serialization/deserialization).

If you choose to go this route also invest time comparing BSON vs JSON as I think it would be likely that the binary encoded one will offer even more space savings (and further IO reduction) due to the size of your object graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a .NET expert but maybe using a binary serialization would increase throughput.  Making sure that the XML isn't stored as text (fairly obvious but thought I'd mention it). Also relational databases are best for storing relational data, so perhaps substituting an ORM layer in place of the serialization (sounds feasible) could speed things up.

Comment: ++ You're giving a guess, but I wouldn't be surprised if you're right.

Comment: We use binary serialization to persist XML in the Db.

Comment: .... what? @Priest did you say you serialize your objects to XML and then serialize the XML into binary and save the binary itself then?

Comment: @Priest: I think @Novikov was suggesting getting XML out of the loop, since it increases space by several times, and the generation and parsing of it can be a real "bottleneck", which should be trivial to verify with a few stackshots.

Answer (score 1):

Mike is spot on, without understanding the resource constaint leading to the performance issues, no amount of discussion will resolve the problem. I'll add that socket timeouts that affect running statements are a symptom, and are never imposed by SQL Server, they're an artifact of your driver configuration or a firewall or similar device between app and db imposing them (unless you're talking about timeouts for new connections, then you have a host in serious distress under load).

Given your symptom is database timeouts, you need to start there. If they're indicative of long running statements that result in a socket timeout, use SQL Server profiler to capture the workload while simultaneously monitoring system resources. Given it's a mature application and the type of workload you mention, it's unlikely to be statement tuning related, it probably boils down to resource limitations CPU, memory or disk IO capacity

This Technet guide is a very good place to start:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx

If it's resource contention, then it's a simple discussion about how the resource contention can be tuned, configured for or addressed by adding more of whatever is needed.

Edit: I should add that given a database performance issue, more applications servers is likely to worsen the problem as you increase the amount of concurrency, that might otherwise be kept in check by connection pool, request processing or other limits.