# A tool to measure if some task is heavy or not?

Tags: android

Is there a tool which I can use to measure how much the execution of a task lasts?

If yes, how many milliseconds is enough to consider a task being heavy task?

Saying "heavy task" meaning that I am contemplating whether to send this task to background thread or not. Sending it would mean a couple of days of extra work to adopt the structure to it. And I would not like to send it to background thread if I don't have to.

Comment: Delaying the UI thread by more than a handful of milliseconds is a bad idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871311/how-can-i-profile-my-android-app

Comment: @RobertHarvey - this should not be closed as off topic, but rather marked as a duplicate of your link.